# Delete multiple iptables with line number (for loop)

Tags: bash, loops, grep, iptables, openvpn

I have VPN server where specific routes that are pushed to clients upon connection initialization and I'm trying to write the bash script to drop the routes when the client disconnects.

I currently have this but it only drops the 1st entry and I need it to drop all line-numbers that are returned.

```
get_iptables_rule_by_comment () {
  echo $(sudo /sbin/iptables -nL FORWARD --line-numbers | grep "$common_name" | cut -f1 -d" " | sed -n '1p')
}
```

So if I have two entries that match in the iptables it will print the line-numbers `7` & `8`

Deletes the first returned line number

```
rule_number=$(get_iptables_rule_by_comment)
if [ "$rule_number" ]; then
  sudo /sbin/iptables -D FORWARD $rule_number
fi


exit 0
```

Can someone help me write the for loop so I can drop the second and third if there was one. It's probably simple just can't wrap my head around it. I'm new to bash scripting.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it. You can use `for rule_number in $(get_iptables_rule_by_comment); do ... done` or `get_iptables_rule_by_comment | while read rule_number; do ... done`. Also, note that `echo $( iptables ...)` is kind of redundant `iptables ...` is enough (you are capturing the output just to print it out).